# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'std' defined in file

Tags: spring

```
package com.nareshit.beans;

public class Address {
    private String city,state;
    public String toString()
    {
    return "\n city:"+city+"\nstate:"+state;    
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}

package com.nareshit.clients;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.beans.Beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.nareshit.beans.Student;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("MyBeans.xml"));

        Student std1=(Student)factory.getBean("std");

        std1.getStudentDetails();
    }
}


package com.nareshit.beans;

public class Student {
    private int sid;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public void getStudentDetails()
        {
        System.out.println("student id:"+sid);
        System.out.println("student name:"+name);
        System.out.println("student address:"+address);
        }

    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}

    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
                "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
    <beans>
    <bean id="std" class="com.nareshit.beans.Student">
    <property name="std" value="1001"/>
    <property name="name" value="mitu"/>
    <property name="address" ref="addressObj"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="addressObj" class="com.nareshit.beans.Address">
    <property name="city" value="bam"/>
    <property name="state" value="odisha"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

This is the spring setter injection prog. where i am getting error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'std' defined in file("")

how to solve it?

Comment: thanks i got it but it is not working  ....

Answer (score -1):

Please see **com.nareshit.beans.Student** class. It is having one property named as *address* which is a type of **String**. When you are writing the XML,
you are giving one reference type of **`com.nareshit.beans.Address`**.

**Solution :**
 1. You can give a String value in the XML for address property.like

```
ddress property like
       <bean id="std" class="com.nareshit.beans.Student">
    <property name="std" value="1001"/>
    <property name="name" value="mitu"/>
    <property name="address" value="SOME ADDRESS"/>
    </bean>
```

2. You can change the type of address property in Student Class like

```
public class Student{
    Address address;
    //declaration of rest property
//Some Boiler Plate Code
}
```